# Protect a nested object against flattening when using pandas.json_normalize

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, json-normalize

In pandas >= 1.1.4 / Python 3, I would like to *protect* a nested element against flattening when using [json_normalize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html).

I cannot figure out such thing in the documentation.

#### Actual example

Here's a concrete example to figure out the main idea:

```py
res='''
    {
      "results": [
        {
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "crs": 4326,
            "coordinates": 
              [[
                  [6.0, 49.0],
                  [6.0, 40.0],
                  [7.0, 40.0],
                  [7.0, 49.0],
                  [6.0, 49.0]
              ]]
          },
          "attribute": "layer.metadata",
          "bbox": [6, 40, 7, 49],
          "featureName": "Coniferous_Trees",
          "layerName": "State_Forests",
          "type": "Feature",
          "id": "17",
          "properties": {
            "resolution": "100",
            "Year": "2020",
            "label": "Coniferous"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
'''
```

This is a single JSON record from an API response. Here, there is only one element in the top level list, but there my be more, each following the same structure as the one shown here. I'd like to import this into a [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) without columns containing structured element, namely, I want to flatten / normalize them all. Well,... almost all. `json_normalize()` is a doing an amazing job in doing that:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = json.loads(res)['results']
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.json_normalize(data))
```

And here are the columns of the DataFrame:

```py
>>> print(df.columns)
Index(['attribute', 'bbox', 'featureName', 'layerName', 'type', 'id',
       'geometry.type', 'geometry.crs', 'geometry.coordinates', # <-- the geometry has been flattened
       'properties.resolution', 'properties.Year', 'properties.label'],
      dtype='object')
```

#### Wanted behaviour

But I need to, let's say, "protect" the `geometry` object in the input JSON response against flattening so that I end up with these columns instead:

```py
# e.g. something like this:
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.json_normalize(data, protect="results.geometry"))
# or this if there isn't two objects with the same name:
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.json_normalize(data, protect="geometry"))
```

which would lead to:

```py
>>> print(df.columns)

Index(['attribute', 'bbox', 'featureName', 'layerName', 'type', 'id',
       'geometry', 'properties.resolution', # <-- the geometry element has been protected!
       'properties.Year', 'properties.label'],
      dtype='object')
```

Is there a way of doing that properly?

Answer (score 0):

Consider `max_level=0`. Per [**`pandas.json_normalize`** docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

> **max_level : *int, default None*** 
> Max number of levels(depth of dict) to normalize. if None, normalizes all levels.

```py
data = json.loads(response)["results"]
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.json_normalize(data, max_level=0))

print(df.T)
#                                                              0
# geometry     {'type': 'Polygon', 'crs': 4326, 'coordinates'...
# attribute                                       layer.metadata
# bbox                                            [6, 40, 7, 49]
# featureName                                   Coniferous_Trees
# layerName                                        State_Forests
# type                                                   Feature
# id                                                          17
# properties   {'resolution': '100', 'Year': '2020', 'label':...

print(df.columns)
# Index(['geometry', 'attribute', 'bbox', 'featureName', 'layerName', 'type', 'id', 
#        'properties'], dtype='object')
```

And since all nested objects are not normalized, use data wrangling to unwind needed columns like `properties`:

```py
df = (
       df.drop(['properties'], axis="columns")
         .join(df["properties"].dropna().apply(pd.Series))
     )


print(df.T)
#                                                              0
# geometry     {'type': 'Polygon', 'crs': 4326, 'coordinates'...
# attribute                                       layer.metadata
# bbox                                            [6, 40, 7, 49]
# featureName                                   Coniferous_Trees
# layerName                                        State_Forests
# type                                                   Feature
# id                                                          17
# resolution                                                 100
# Year                                                      2020
# label                                               Coniferous

print(df.columns)
# Index(['geometry', 'attribute', 'bbox', 'featureName', 'layerName', 'type', 'id',
#        'resolution', 'Year', 'label'], dtype='object')
```